# How to use MVC pattern in Swift for Networking?

Tags: swift, parsing, networking, styles

I just want to know what is the best practice for Networking in Swift? For example, if I want to fetch data using different Flickr methods, should I create a single NetworkingManager, that will send all requests, and appropriate DataModels? Or it is better to create only necessary DataModels and inside create a function that will do networking (but there will be a code duplication)?? 
THNX!

Answer (score 0):

you can create as many clients as you want

e.g. loginClient class for the login call
     profileClient class for getting profile data

or you can add both of them into a userClient(). it does not matter.You can make a folder name RestClients or Application Services.

for best practice what i would do is create necessary DataModels and map incoming data through it to create object.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion best practice would be using classes and protocols as networkManager:
1-a Client class where you define your get/post/... methods
2-Create an Enum and define ur APIs 
3- create your data models
4- create Services class where you fully define your APIs and how they should work
I can send you a sample if you wish :)